# Changing cooldown spam for discord.js

Tags: discord

I am making a discord economy bot and I want I cooldown. I have made a functioning cooldown but it spams the message that it’s on cooldown. Is there any way to make it only say it’s on cooldown once? Here’s my cooldown code:

```
var cooldown = false;
client.on("message", (message) => {
      if (message.author.bot) return;

      if (message.content.includes("gg!work")) {
        if (cooldown == true) {

          //Bot is on a cooldown
          return;

        } else {
          message.channel.send("Calm down your on cooldown");

          cooldown = true;
          setTimeout(() => {
            cooldown = false
          }, 7000); //Cooldown for 7 seconds
        }
      }
    }
```

My command code is

```
    if (message.content.toUpperCase() === 'GG!WORK'){
    var work_check = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

    money.updateBal(message.author.id, work_check).then((i) => {
      message.channel.send('You worked and got '+work_check+' dollars! '+`New balance: ${i.money}`)
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple boolean lock.

```
if (allow) {
    message.channel.send("Calm down your on cooldown");
    allow = false;
}
```

And here,

```
setTimeout(() => {
    cooldown = false;
    allow = true
}, 7000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something like this in your command code?

```js
 var cooldown = false;
   if (message.content.toUpperCase() === 'GG!WORK' && cooldown == false){
    var work_check = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);

    money.updateBal(message.author.id, work_check).then((i) => {
      message.channel.send('You worked and got '+work_check+' dollars! '+`New balance: ${i.money}`);
          cooldown = true;
          setTimeout(() => {
            cooldown = false
          }, 7000); //Cooldown for 7 seconds
    });
  } else {
     message.channel.send("Calm down your\'re on a cooldown");
}
```

although this probably isn't the best way to do that.